# Making Content disappear using CSS

Tags: html, css, graphics

I'm trying to use HTML and CSS only on something testing. I was able to get the list to appear in a box after the circle is clicked on. The issue I'm having is when the circle is not active the list is still clickable. If you hover on the bottom right you will be able to click on the list and activate it. Is there a way to make it only clickable only when the box appears? Included a picture of the area where the list is when the circle is not activated. Thank you for any help.

```css
  html {
    background: #1a1a1a;
    color: #e5e5e5;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Univers, Futura, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  body {
    max-width: 1200px;

    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  .description {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.7);
  }

  div {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 9pt;
    margin-bottom: 1pt;
    margin-top: 2.5pt;
    margin-left: 2px;
    z-index: 5;
  }

  a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  label {
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin-bottom: 0pt;
    margin-top: 0pt;
    margin-left: 8px;
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  /*
        .centered {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
*/

  .test {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    right: 2px;
  }

  .centered-y {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

  .distribution-map {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .distribution-map .map-point {
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
    background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
    border: 2.5px solid #cf2045;
  }

  .distribution-map .map-point .content {

    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    overflow: overlay;
  }

  .distribution-map .map-point:active,
  .distribution-map .map-point:focus {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #e5e5e5;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
  }

  .distribution-map .centered-y .map-point:active .content ,
  .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {

    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover,
  .distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active,
  .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover,
  .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
    color: #afe1fa;
  }
```

```html
<div class="distribution-map">
  <button type="radio" class="map-point" style="top:130%;left:39%">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="centered-y">
        <ol>
        <li>Site01</li>
        <li>Site02</li>
        <li>Site03</li>
        <li>Site04</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8otv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Setting an element's `opacity` doesn't cause it to be hidden in the way you might expect. It can still be interacted with as though it were still fully opaque. For some types of elements, this includes being able to navigate to them via the keyboard, and they'll also be visible to assistive technology such as screen readers.

The approach I typically use when I need to hide or show an element with an animation is to animate the element's `visibility`, because unlike the `display` property the `visibility` value can be animated.

Here are the standard animations I like to use for this, which will make an element either appear immediately or disappear at the end of an animation period:

```
@keyframes becomeVisible {
      0% { visibility: visible; }
    100% { visibility: visible; }
}
@keyframes becomeHidden {
      0% { visibility: visible; }
    100% { visibility: visible; }
    100% { visibility: hidden; }
}
@media (prefers-reduced-motion) {
    /* becomeVisible already suits prefers-reduced-motion */

    @keyframes becomeHidden {
          0% { visibility: hidden; }
        100% { visibility: hidden; }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, because of the way the visibility property is interpolated, it's more difficult to use with transitions because it will switch values at the mid-way point of the transition. That's why I prefer doing it via an animation instead.

If you haven't used CSS animations before, here's a useful reference and guide: [Using CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)